# Optional voids in interface C#

Tags: c#, plugins, interface

Hello i have made an plugin interface which looks like this

```
 public  interface IPluginInterface :IEquatable<IPluginInterface>
{
    string Maker { get; }
    string Version { get; }  
    void Do();
    void Do_two();
}
```

I have tried, but havent found any way to make strings Maker and Version optional ,
I think i have to set a boolean Equals, but dont know how to .
Thank you for help

Answer (score 5):

If you declared them in the interface, they *must* be implemented.

You can't have optional members declared on an interface.

There are several options for you:

- Break up the interface into two. Only implement what you need.
- Implement an abstract class with the "optional" members being empty and non abstract.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mark any interface methods as optional - either you implement the whole interface or you don't implement it at all!

You can consider splitting this interface into two different ones instead.

Answer (score 1):

Split the interface into several:

```
public interface IPluginInterface : IEquatable<IPluginInterface>
{
    string Maker { get; }
    string Version { get; }  
}

public interface IPluginWithOptionA : IPluginInterface
{
    void Do();
}

public interface IPluginWithOptionB : IPluginInterface
{
    void Do_two();
}
```

you can either implement one or more interfaces

```
public class MyPlugin : IPluginWithOptionA, IPluginWithOptionB
{
    public bool Equals(IPluginInterface other)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string Maker
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public string Version
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public void Do_two()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An interface is the wrong way if you want to have this methods optional. but u can put them into an abstract base-class.